# JNumberTextField: Why is not work

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

but i read about it on youtube and how to set `JTextField` as a `JNumberTextField` . because i want input only number. If anyone press other key then char not show in text field

```
import javax.swing.*;
    public class example {
        public static void main(String aa[])
        {
            JNumberTextField num = JNumberTextField();
            num.setColumns(15);
            num.setFormat(JNumberTextField.DECIMAL);
            num.setPrecision(4);
            num.setAllowNegative(false);

            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.add(num);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(200,200);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
```

I am using JNumberTextField because of i want input only number but it is not work. i am reading about it on youtube tutorials

**error is**

```
loop.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JNumberTextField
location: class example
        JNumberTextField num = JNumberTextField()
        ^
loop.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method JNumberTextField()
location: class example
        JNumberTextField num = JNumberTextField()
                               ^
loop.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable JNumberTextField
location: class example
        num.setFormat(JNumberTextField.DECIMAL);
```

They are using there own custom class.

Comment: what is not working? error ? exception?

Comment: Where did you set `JNumberTextField` in your classpath?

Comment: `JNumberTextField` is not a standard component in the JSE

Comment: but i read about it on youtube

Comment: They are using there own custom class.  Do a Google for "java JNumberTextField" and see what you find, you won't get any results from any official JSE documentation.  But I've only been using the API for 15+ years and I've never seen it

Comment: You should "new" it too like this: JNumberTextField num = new JNumberTextField();

Comment: No they only use import javax.swing.*;

Comment: Link for the video please

Comment: Do you want input only Integer?

Comment: yeah [Michael Kazarian](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2404181/michael-kazarian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using there own custom class.
and if you want only input number then use formated textfield